# Server side validation php

Tags: php

I am trying to validate my page server side in php...to do that I have to do post to same page in order to check the controls values. But after validation succeeds, how do i redirect to another page using post method? I can accomplish this using get But is there a way out to redirect page using post method from with the in the code itself?

In simple words I am trying to look for a solution to redirect my page using post method but from with my php code and not setting the action attribute in form tag.

Thanks,

Rizwan

Comment: POST will ask for re submission of the content. It is used to submit values from client to server side. If you validated the values server side you just serve a page with GET request. What are you trying to achieve by piling post requests? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You might find what you are looking for [here](http://goo.gl/nJxqI)

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to another page from your PHP code, when you want to GET the new page:

```
<?php
  header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other"); 
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/page/to/redirect-to.html");
?>
```

I'm using 303 here, as the [HTTP/1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) says:

> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to redirect the user agent to a selected resource.

and redirecting using 301, 302 or 307 [doesn't always get you a redirect-to-GET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> action="post">
```

... rest of form code

for your submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="formsubmit" value="submit button text" />
```

Somewhere towards the top of your page

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['formsubmit))
{
  //do validation and if validated - redirect to new page
}
  else {
 // display errors and current page with form again
}
?>
```